# Is there a model of a legal defense similar to the kill chain?

Tags: criminal-law

The kill chain is a model of an attack used by the military.  It breaks an attack into multiple phases so if you stop the attack at any phase you win.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_chain

Is there a model of a legal defense similar to the kill chain?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you think the legal equivalent of a “kill chain” would be? Or do you just mean scenarios where a necessary step in a legal argument can be refuted? For example, if a suspected murderer can show that they couldn't have been at the scene, then the prosecution's argument would collapse. Or as a civil example, if someone sues for wrongful termination, that argument would collapse if they were never employed by the defendant.

Answer (score 1):

The *kill chain* concept explains how several units cooperate in an attack. One unit detects a target, a commander allocates weapons to the target, another unit launches the attack, perhaps another unit provides target designation.

The legal equivalent would be either [accessory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessory_(legal_term)) to murder or [felony murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_murder_rule) in many jurisdictions. Everybody who participates in a crime which results in a death is held responsible for that death, even if that person did not pull the trigger himself or herself. And organized crime bosses can usually be punished for murder when they order a hit, even if they were nowhere near the crime scene.